# mysql - match an array of years for datetime field

Tags: php, mysql

is it possible to match array of years in a single query for dateTime format as example 2017-12-12 00:00:00

i tried it like this but its not working.

```
$years=implode(",",$year);
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE YEAR(reg-date) = '$years';
```

it will only return the first year in the array.

How can I query the table to return all the years in the array?

Comment: Use the "IN" in the query like this: SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE YEAR(reg-date) in ( $years);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the MySQL function `IN()`. To match the year of your values, you should use `YEAR()` on those as well, and not just the column-name.

```
$years = implode("'), YEAR('",$year);
```

Then the query would be run as

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE YEAR(`reg-date`) IN (YEAR('$years'));
```

Note that this is not an ideal way of doing it. You should use a prepared statement with placeholder instead - but without seeing which API you are using, its hard to show exactly how you would go about that.

You should also avoid having a hyphen in your column-name, as MySQL then would think you are doing subtraction. If you do have it, wrap the name in backticks.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, it's better to use a prepared statement for this. Which PHP version and API are you using? To find any errors in your query, can you print the final querystring and post that here?

Comment: your solution actually works..there is problem in my code..i fixed it now its ok..